# Find Combinations of Values in a Single Column - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a Input Table of this structure

Input :

Col1 | Col2 | Col3

---

O1  |   P1  | 100
O1  |   P2  | 200
O1  |   P3  | 300
O2  |   P1  | 100
O2  |   P2  | 200

I need to find the Different Combinations and aggregate the Values in another Column at the same time.

Output Expected :

Col1 | Col2 | COl3

---

O1  |   P1,P2   | 300

O1  |   P2,P3   | 500

O1  |   P3,P1   | 400

O1  |   P1,P2,P3 |600

O2  |   P1,P2   | 300

Need some help in how to approach this Problem and Where to start.

Comment: Man, I had your answer and then you *completely* changed the question. :( For the previous version, `string_agg` would have been a simple solution. Have a look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: Class homework? (It's fine if so, but say if it is.)

Comment: Haha.. It's not class homework LOL. I have Recreated one of the  Business Problems in sales Here.

Comment: Thanks Though @opatut

Comment: Is there a maximum number of different values (es. P4, P5, ... ) for same COL1?

Comment: Also, is there a minimum, e.g. of 2? In your example result, you're "missing" entries like `O1 | | 0` and `O1 | P1 | 100` otherwise.

Comment: There is no limit for maximum number of different values in col2. ANd there is minimum number of Different Values - Which is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (where X is your table):

```
WITH RECURSIVE R  AS (SELECT X.COL1, X.COL2, CAST(X.COL2 AS VARCHAR(100)) AS COMBI, COL3 AS TOT
           FROM X
           UNION ALL
           SELECT X.COL1, X.COL2,  CAST( r.COMBI || CAST(',' AS VARCHAR(1)) || X.COL2  AS VARCHAR(100)), X.COL3+R.TOT AS TOT
            FROM R 
            INNER JOIN X ON X.COL2 > R.COL2 AND X.COL1 = R.COL1)
SELECT COL1, COMBI, TOT 
FROM R
WHERE LENGTH(COMBI) >LENGTH(COL2)
ORDER BY COL1, LENGTH(COMBI), COMBI
;
```

Output (with data as you posted):

```
    col1    combi   tot
1   O1  P1,P2   300
2   O1  P1,P3   400
3   O1  P2,P3   500
4   O1  P1,P2,P3    600
5   O2  P1,P2   300
```

Output (adding another row P4 in O1):

```
    col1    combi   tot
1   O1  P1,P2   300
2   O1  P1,P3   400
3   O1  P1,P4   500
4   O1  P2,P3   500
5   O1  P2,P4   600
6   O1  P3,P4   700
7   O1  P1,P2,P3    600
8   O1  P1,P2,P4    700
9   O1  P1,P3,P4    800
10  O1  P2,P3,P4    900
11  O1  P1,P2,P3,P4 1000
12  O2  P1,P2   300
```

Comment: Thanks, Etsa. You saved me hours of Work.

Comment: @esta, can you please have a look on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66794991/postgresql-find-common-combination-of-pairs-on-same-column