# PostgreSQL find common combination of pairs on same column

Tags: postgresql, group-by

**WHAT I NEED**

Find pairs of platforms that platform2 offers more
than 50% of the series offered by platform1. Return pairs of platforms (renamed platform1,
platform2) and proportion of series they have in common (numcommon)

**WHAT I TRIED:** Here I've multiple series are broadcast on different platform. I just added couple of them. For example:

**Full Dataset:**

```
|seriesid|platform       |
|--------|---------------|
|4       |Netflix        |
|6       |Netflix        |
|8       |Netflix        |
|13      |Netflix        |
|13      |TNT            |
|13      |Free Services  |
|16      |Hulu           |
|16      |Netflix        |
|16      |Free Services  |
|20      |Netflix        |
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

By using the query of @**Julius**

**Current Query**

```
select 
  sp1.platform as platform1, sp2.platform as platform2, count(*) as numcommon 
from 
  seriesonplatform AS sp1
  JOIN seriesonplatform AS sp2 ON (sp1.seriesid = sp2.seriesid) AND (sp1.platform <>  sp2.platform)
group by
  sp1.platform,
  sp2.platform
order by sp1.platform, sp2.platform,numcommon
```

**Current Output**

```
    |platform1|platform2      |numcommon|
|---------|---------------|---------|
|A&E      |Free Services  |1        |
|A&E      |Prime Video    |1        |
|AcornTV  |CBS All Access |1        |
|AcornTV  |Free Services  |1        |
|AcornTV  |Hoopla         |2        |
|AcornTV  |Hulu           |1        |
|AcornTV  |Netflix        |6        |
|AcornTV  |Prime Video    |2        |
|Adult Swim|Free Services  |1        |
|Adult Swim|HBO MAX        |1        |
|BET      |BET+           |1        |
|BET      |Free Services  |1        |
|BET+     |BET            |1        |
|BET+     |Free Services  |1        |
|Bravo    |Free Services  |1        |
|Bravo    |Netflix        |2        |
|BritBox  |Hoopla         |2        |
|CBS All Access|AcornTV        |1        |
|CBS All Access|Free Services  |6        |
|CBS All Access|Hulu           |1        |
|CBS All Access|Netflix        |7        |
|CBS All Access|fuboTV         |2        |
|Cartoon Network|Free Services  |2        |
|Cartoon Network|HBO MAX        |2        |
|Cartoon Network|Hulu           |1        |
|Cartoon Network|Netflix        |1        |
|Comedy Central|Hoopla         |1        |
|Comedy Central|Netflix        |1        |
|Crunchyroll|Free Services  |3        |
```

**Expected Output**

```
    platform1    |   platform2   | numcommon 
-----------------+---------------+-----------
 AcornTV         | Netflix       |      0.60
 Adult Swim      | Free Services |      1.00
 Adult Swim      | HBO MAX       |      1.00
 BET             | BET+          |      1.00
 BET             | Free Services |      1.00
 BET+            | BET           |      1.00
 BET+            | Free Services |      1.00
 Bravo           | Netflix       |      1.00
 Cartoon Network | Free Services |      0.67
 Cartoon Network | HBO MAX       |      0.67
 CBS All Access  | Netflix       |      0.58
 Crunchyroll     | Free Services |      1.00
 Disney          | Disney+       |      1.00
 Disney          | Free Services |      1.00
 fuboTV          | Netflix       |      0.60
 Funimation      | Free Services |      0.67
 HBO             | HBO MAX       |      1.00
 History         | Hulu          |      0.67
 History         | Netflix       |      0.67
 IFC             | fuboTV        |      0.67
 IFC             | Netflix       |      0.67
 IndieFlix       | Free Services |      1.00
 IndieFlix       | Hoopla        |      1.00
 Lifetime        | Netflix       |      0.67
 Showtime        | fuboTV        |      1.00
 Showtime        | Netflix       |      0.67
 Sundance        | Free Services |      1.00
 Sundance        | Prime Video   |      1.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need a join to find all platform pairs:

```
select 
  sp1.platform as platform1, sp2.platform as platform2, count(*) as numcommon 
from 
  seriesonplatform AS sp1
  JOIN seriesonplatform AS sp2 ON (sp1.seriesid = sp2.seriesid) AND (sp1.platform <>  sp2.platform)
where 
  sp1.platform in ('BET','BET+')
  AND sp2.platform in ('BET','BET+')
group by
  sp1.platform,
  sp2.platform
```

---

EDIT 2

Using the query above you can find the common series number. All is left is finding percentage:

```
SELECT 
  platform1.platform, common.platform2, numcommon * 1.0 / platform1.seriescount AS show_on_platform2
FROM (
  SELECT 
    platform, count(*) AS seriescount
  FROM 
    seriesonplatform
  GROUP BY
    platform 
) platform1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    sp1.platform as platform1, sp2.platform as platform2, count(*) as numcommon 
  FROM 
    seriesonplatform AS sp1
    JOIN seriesonplatform AS sp2 ON (sp1.seriesid = sp2.seriesid) AND (sp1.platform <>  sp2.platform)
  GROUP BY
    sp1.platform,
    sp2.platform
) AS common ON platform1.platform = common.platform1
WHERE 
  numcommon * 1.0 / platform1.seriescount > 0.5
ORDER BY
  platform1.platform, platform2
```

Comment: sir, the query seems almost ok but result is not fully exact. Please have a look on my edit again.

Comment: actually, this is my last concern sir, Find pairs of platforms (renamed platform1, platform2) such that **platform2 offers more than 50% of the series offered by platform1**

Comment: @AlwaysSunny  I'd like you to clarify the problem. Do you need the series to match or is it just the number of distinct series you are interested in and you want to compare how large the platforms are. Or is it the number of common series  - you need to see that platform2 has more than 50% the series the platform1 offers?
You provided expected output, but please provide input you expect the output from - that would be helpfull.

Comment: Something doesn't add up: there are only 2 series (1189 and 2580) on Cartoon Network, one of them (2580) is also on "Free Services".  How come in expected result you get  Cartoon Network, Free Services =>  0.67  ?

Comment: actually I didn't able to post full dataset of my table because of stackoverflow has limitation of character on question post.

Comment: Please try the SQL I've appended to my original answer. It should work for you.

Comment: You are a star, genius.....that's why I like this platform most. Happy coding sir.